# ImageProvider bug - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-assetimage

I'm encountering an Image provider bug that I'm currently stuck trying to fix it(I'm new to Flutter).
The error I'm getting looks like this

> ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:7: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '/'.
> /2rethrow;
> ^

> ../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:8: Error: Expected ';' after this.
> /2rethrow;
> ^

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I have tried fixing it using `flutter clean` but that does not resolve the problem. **NB** I have **assets** directory that contains the images.

**main.dart** looks like

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('my first app'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[600]
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset('assets/2.jpg'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
        child: Text('click'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml** looks like this

```
name: timeApp
description: A new Flutter project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error seems inside
flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\painting\image_provider.dart   had a changed date & got corrupted. Just copy back the same from flutter  installation zip to resolve issue. More investigation is required what exactly happen